# How can I make cygwin autocomplete windows paths?

Tags: cygwin

I don't want to type /cygdrive/c/path/to/stuff, especially when using tools that don't know anything about cygwin. Is there a way to configure cygwin to autocomplete "c:\path\to\stuff" or even "c:/path/to/stuff"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For tools that can't understand cygwin paths, you'll need to convert them to windows paths. The `cygpath` utility can do this for you:

```
notepad $(cygpath -w /cygdrive/c/path/to/stuff)
```

You can probably create aliases or wrapper scripts for commonly-used windows executables.

Answer (score 3):

Autocomplete should be working after the /cygdrive/c bit.  Make a symlink for "/cygdrive/c/" to something else, like "ln -s /cygdrive/c /c".  Also, make sure your inputrc is set up correctly.

Comment: self -1: didn't answer your question.  Actually, I have that problem, too, with Gvim for windows.  I usually put the stuff in my cygwin tree, or CD to it and run the Gvim from that directory down "/cygdrive/c/MyDoc..."

Answer (score 0):

Windows itself can autocomplete paths, with some minor [registry tweaks](http://www.gabrielserafini.com/archives/2004/10/26/windows-shell-auto-complete/). Or am I missing something in this question?

Comment: You're missing the point that cygwin is not running cmd.exe but its own bash shell :-).

Comment: Actaully, it is a bash shell in a cmd.exe, again, at least on my box. i've been meaning to run the patch to Putty to host the bash shell locally.

Comment: @Pax: Thanks. I interpreted as cygwin installed giving access to unix-like facilities (ls, pwd, etc) & paths at the Windows command prompt. OP doesn't make it clear which interpretation is correct.

Answer (score 0):

use alias:

Open the .bashrc file already copied in your home directory and type (I use "vi" editor for this but you can use "pico" which is a bit easier):

```
alias C="C:\Documents\ and\ Settings\Administrator"
```

you can use any path here. Save the .bashrc ("Ctrl+X" in pico I think, and :wq in "vi") and close the terminal. After restarting this console, typing "C" and pressing enter will send you automatically to "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator"

To know which alias you have, just type "alias" in your terminal and all your alias will show up.